# iOS Storyboard designed apps

Tags: ios, user-interface, uistoryboard

Ok,

I'm very confused about something...  being new to development on iOS I'm often pushed towards the storyboard/graphical design (specially to make file owner, segue, etc type of connections). HOWEVER; every time there's something besides a basic (dare I say primitive) design, I have to do things via code...    problem is that just because you can do something via code doesn't make it right according to Apple. so you have to know all the rules to have you app approved.    Even some of the examples from Apple (UISPLITVIEW with multiple view controllers -> MultipleDetailViews) do not have story boards just XIB... is that normal???

So question is: why have graphical design if you have to move towards coded solutions anyway. just to say that you have an easy to program interface?

can anyone help me understand that??

cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

Three things (at least!) are going on here:

- Storyboards are relatively new and a lot of examples existed before storyboards were introduced.
- People are always dreaming up things that are more complex than a very high-level approach can handle.  (Even with .xib files, which are more flexible than storyboards, people write custom code to get around limitations.)
- For examples, code is linear and a bit easier to follow than the description of a bunch of clicks and drags.

Answer (score 2):

So, first of all, a storyboard is nothing more than a conglomerate of .xib files. When you use storyboards, Xcode handles unloading all the nibs for you. At its core, your app still uses these nib files.

Additionally, your app won't get rejected if you use code to set a property instead of setting it in Interface Builder, or vice versa. I don't know that I would say Apple's stance is just because you can do something in code doesn't make it right. I would argue that they urge developers to set as many properties via IB because less code that you write means less bugs that you introduce. If I have a view in a nib, and I check its "hidden" property in IB, that's no different than me saying view.hidden = YES in code. Apple doesn't prefer one over the other. But using IB relieves me from having to know that the property to hide a view is "hidden" and that it accepts a BOOL as an argument. If in iOS6 they decide to make it shouldHideSelf, using IB's hidden property will be automatically updated, where as I would have to manually update my programmatic setting of the hidden property.